# Can't get data from quotes_historical_yahoo_ochl

Tags: python, matplotlib, finance

I am trying to draw a k line of stock.

```
import matplotlib.finance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start_date = (2006, 10, 1)
end_date = (2017, 10, 1)

quotes = mpf.quotes_historical_yahoo_ochl('AAPL',start_date, end_date)
fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
mpf.candlestick_ochl(ax,quotes,width=0.6,colorup='r',colordown='g')
plt.grid(True)
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(),rotation=30)
plt.show()
```

It always return error like

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I tried print quotes. It will return None.

Comment: The [Yahoo finance API is discontinued](https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/Is-Yahoo-Finance-API-broken/td-p/250503/page/3). You will not be able to get data from it anymore. Hence the `quotes_historical_yahoo_..` functions have become obsolete.